# how to find location of column in pivot table

Tags: python, pandas, pivot, pivot-table

Hi I have a pivot table using pivot_table() method.

I want to find out the column where the value in the row is the highest. I'm not sure how to iterate through a pivot

this pivot_df

```
EventID 1.0 2.0 3.0 4.0 5.0 6.0
Name                        
John    10  90  0   70  30  50
Berry   20  50  30  0   0   0
Charles 50  20  0   80  40  60
Susan   60  30  30  0   30  0
Elisa   200 30  30  100 0   0
```

Expected output:

```
Give me the eventID for highest amount of Charles = 4.0
Give me the eventID for highest amount of John = 2.0
```

I tried .loc method but only if I know the EventID. I only have the name and amount

```
pivot_df.loc(Berry,3.0)  = 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is `.loc` and `idxmax`

```
df.loc['Charles'].idxmax()

Out[151]: 4.0

df.loc['John'].idxmax()

Out[150]: 2.0
```

---

If you want to get both at the same time

```
df.idxmax(1).loc[['Charles', 'John']]

Out[153]:
Charles    4.0
John       2.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: @user11666514: you are welcome. Glad I could help :)